# What's the benefit of helper class when calling from JS to .NET component instance .NET method in Blazor

Tags: blazor

The blazor docs recommends to use helper class when [calling from JavaScript to .NET component instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-6.0#component-instance-net-method-helper-class).

The helper class does nothing but delegates to component methods anyway:

```cs
public class MessageUpdateInvokeHelper
{
    private Action action;

    public MessageUpdateInvokeHelper(Action action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }

    [JSInvokable("BlazorSample")]
    public void UpdateMessageCaller()
    {
        action.Invoke();
    }
}
```

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS

@code {
    private string message = "Select one of these list item buttons.";
    private MessageUpdateInvokeHelper? messageUpdateInvokeHelper;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        messageUpdateInvokeHelper = new MessageUpdateInvokeHelper(UpdateMessage);
    }

    private void UpdateMessage()
    {
        message = "UpdateMessage Called!";
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

**Why not just define [JSInvokable] on the component instance?**

```
@code {
    private string message = "Select one of these list item buttons.";

    [JSInvokable("BlazorSample")]
    private void UpdateMessage()
    {
        message = "UpdateMessage Called!";
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling a JS method should be seen as equivalent to making an API call etc and as such should be separated from the UI logic. Cleaner to keep separation of concerns.  The link itself explains the situations.  1) When several components of the same type are rendered on the same page.
2) In a Blazor Server apps, where multiple users concurrently use the same component.

Comment: @MayurEkbote: I don't quite understand. Actually I don't undestand at all what you mean :O
I know what a separation of contern is, but see how it does apply here. Nothing is separated, there is just a roundtrip to another class and back. Regarding 1) and 2), I have no idea how is that relevant

Comment: (a) Blazor components are 'technically' classes. However, you will never instantiate these on your own. Therefore, the methods on these will be invokable only in that class. (b) A JS interop is required when you want to have functionality that is available through JS but not through Blazor. Eg. getting viewport dimensions. Also, the other way around - i.e. invoking a function from JS to Blazor. Now, if you put your JSInvokable in your Blazor component, you are trying to access an external functionality through a Blazor class which will not be externally used - by (a) and (b).

Comment: Shouldn't be JavaScript written specifically for the component (i.e it keeps DotNetObjectReference) threated as an implementation detail of the Component, just like HTML or CSS? In .NET 6 there are even component.razor.js files, where the naming implies, that it is part of the component. I still find this little superficial to be presented in the documentation as the default way of calling from JS to .NET. Maybe there is a technical reason related to DotNetObjectReference?

Comment: There is generally no good reason for a Blazor component to have a JSInvokable method. Surely there are use cases (building a Blazor wrapper on JS library  - like charting - that can be quickly deployed on a Blazor app). But generally, I think Microsoft  doesn't want people to treat a Blazor component as another DOM object and build an app that is mostly JS, but on Blazor. Their advice reflects that IMO.

Comment: I initially thought that when we use several instance of a component in a page, since the method are same name, JS may have difficulty on finding which method instance to invoke but I test it find out that this is not the case. Even Number of JSInvokable in both approach are same. I think Helper class are useful when you do not want to expose component to JS and simply expose a helper class instance. Also in Blazor server they may have other advantage which I do not test!

Comment: I test Blazor Server too. Both approaches work same